# Dynamically set scrollEnabled to False in RN ScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-scrollview

How can I change the bool value of `scrollEnabled` param of React Native ScrollView when scrolling reaches a certain position?

I do have a ScrollView inside a ScrollView, and the inner ScrollView doesn't respond because of the outer ScrollView. Inner ScrollView works when `scrollEnabled` param is set to `False` of outer ScrollView. My idea is to dynamically set outer ScrollView to `scrollEnabled={false}` when reaches at the bottom. How do I do this.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Use states. 'scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}' then this.setState({scrollEnabled: false});

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to accomplish this. The first one, as described by @binchik, is to set scrollEnabled to a state variable and update the state when necessary. Of course, this triggers a re-render, which can be problematic. The second way is to update the prop on the ScrollView component directly without re-rendering. You can do it like this:

```
class DisableScrollWithoutRerender extends React.Component {
  listRef = React.createRef();
  ...
  render() {
    return <ScrollView ref={this.listRef} />;
  }

  disableScroll() {
    const { current: list } = this.listRef;
    list.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: false });
  }
}
```

Personally I would recommend to stick to the first option when a re-render is affordable and avoid the second one unless it's exactly what you need.

Comment: You can find more details [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation).

Comment: I'm aware that this answer is 1.5 years late, but perhaps it will be helpful to someone who stumbles upon this question in the future.

Comment: I had to use `this.listRef.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: false });` instead of `disableScroll()`

Comment: I would use this solution when you need scrolling to be disabled immediately. For example, when starting a drag-n-drop for something embedded in a scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a `ref` to your scrollview/listview. and then use following to change scrollEnabled value.

```
render() {
  return <ScrollView ref="scrollView" />;
}

onSomeEvent() {
  this.refs.scrollView.setScrollEnabled(true); // will enable scroll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView component has a prop callback function `onScroll: ({nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y}}, contentSize: {height}})`.

So you could have a `scrollEnabled` variable in your state. and set it to `true` if the `contentOffset.y` is equal to or more than the `contentSize.height` and `false` otherwise.

Make sure that you do not make unnecessary `setState` calls. Since it will make the component rerender every time even if the previous state is exactly the same to the new one.